# setText to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having trouble creating a simple app, I created a variable that changes when you click a button, but I would like to know how to set my TextView to that variable.

total is my TextView, and count is my variable.

I am trying 
total.setText(count);

I dont know how to tell it to just take the value of count and set the text to that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to give your TextView an ID in the layout file:

```
<TextView
    <!-- existing code -->
    android:id="@+id/total">
</TextView>
```

Then use something like this to get the instance of the TextView and set the text:

```
TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
total.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
total.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create a `Global Variable`

and

Modify its value on `Button press` and then call the value in the `TextView`

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Huuummmm

total.setText(String.valueOf(count));

That should do it.

Comment: How come the post isn't helpful? If it isn't can you post why?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but `String` has no `parseInt()` method. And even if it did, I imagine that would return an `int`, which `setText()` will not accept.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `count` is an `int`, and your `TextView` is an instance of [`android.widget.TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html):

```
total.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

`setText()` takes an argument of type [`CharSequence`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and so an `int` needs to be converted to an object type that implements the [`CharSequence`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface. [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is the obvious choice.

Comment: I have an error on 'parseInt'      The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Whoops. I meant `toString()`, not `parseInt()`. Updated. Try again, please.

Comment: toString() works perfectly.  Thank you so much, this was giving me alot of trouble.

Comment: @user888712: No problem. If you wouldn't mind, please upvote and mark my answer correct by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski: I had a silly mistake in my answer at the time of the downvote, and so I deserved it. But I've since corrected the mistake so hopefully the downvoter will change it to an upvote.